# How to use a test plan (it is a manual test) on Azure devops 2019 CI/CD pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2019

Righ now, I am setting a CI/CD pipeline on Azure devops 2019. I have implemented some Autometed test, but I would like to know if there is a way to set a stage in a pipeline with a task that allow me to trigger a manual test created on test plans ?

Comment: Since it is the manual test, what's the requirement you need to trigger a manual test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this first we need to [Associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops). Then you can use [Visual Studio Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops#arguments) by selecting tests using Test Plan to run tests from your test plan that have an automated test method associated with it.

A similar question has been answered on the [Comments](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/testmanagement/#comment-4570332246) in Azure DevOps Labs.Please refer to it.